# how to send request payload through curl in php

Tags: javascript, php, web-services, curl, web-scraping

I am using curl in php to login in danamon bank. I am logged in but then i tried to post request payload in json using json encode like below -

```
$data = [
      '__EVENTTARGET'        => $eventTarget,
      '__EVENTARGUMENT'        => $eventArgument,
      '__LASTFOCUS'        => '',
      '__VIEWSTATE'        => $__VIEWSTATE,
      'hdnActionCd'        => '',
      'hdnRandomKey'        => '',
      'hdnWUC'        => 'AcctMgmt/am_AcctSummaryNew_lst',
      'hdnLanguage'        => $hdnLanguage,
      'hdnPortlet'        => '',
      'Portlet1:hdnFunctionId'        => '',
      '_ctl0:_ctl8:ddlExRate'        => '1'
    ];

    $data = json_encode($data);
```

But as I see in browser tools they send like this -

```
usercontrol: AcctMgmt/am_AcctSummaryNew_lst
------WebKitFormBoundaryH03FR3sFh5RDMJKt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTTARGET"
_ctl0:_ctl2
------WebKitFormBoundaryH03FR3sFh5RDMJKt
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTARGUMENT"
09732747-7aad-42cc-94d7-1a77d3413656^003597205313^26^TABUNGAN DANAMON LEBIH^IDR^SA_N422
------WebKitFormBoundaryH03FR3sFh5RDMJKt--
```

I am not sure how they are sending these info to server.
I think they are using put method in a file but i am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found answer to my question.

If you want to send request payload in curl then should use json format to post data add curl header -

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      "Content-Type:multipart/form-data"
    ));
```

in post you need to add -

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '@'.$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem

Write your payload in JSON format in the postfields option of curl

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}');
```

and specify the content type (which you can find in the request headers of your request) in the httpheader option of curl

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
```